# In Java, what is meant by this "double cannot be dereferenced" error?

Tags: java

I have the following code :

```
public class RandomCompliment {

  static final String[] comps  = { "gorgeous butterfly!", "strawberry milkshake!", "calm waterfall", "smart cookie", "big genius", "friendly cat" };

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    for (int i = 0; i < 200 ; i++ ) {
      System.out.print("Good monring, " + comps[(((20) * Math.sin(i)).intValue()) % comps.length]);
    }
  }
}
```

And it is giving me this error :

> C:\Misc_Stuff\RandomScratch>javac RandomCompliment.java
>   RandomCompliment.java:14: double cannot be dereferenced
>                                   System.out.print(" " + comps[   (  ((20) * Math. sin(i)).intValue()  ) % comps.length        ]);
>
> ```
>    ^ 1 error
> ```

What is meant by "dereferenced" here ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Math.sin(i)` returns `double`. You cannot invoke a method (`intValue()`) on a `double` (or any primitive data-type). Instead, you can down-cast `double` to `int`:

```
(int) (20 * Math.sin(i))
```

Comment: He's using intValue() though.

Comment: @YassinHajaj `intValue()` is a method.

Comment: @YassinHajaj it is not possible to call ` intValue()` on primitive type int

Comment: Ok this wasn't clear before Fouad edited the answer. Thx